# Socket IO listener not working in Android

Tags: websocket, socket.io, android-tv, socketserver

I am working on the notification of an Android TV. I have implemented it using the Socket IO server connection. I have established a connection with Socket Server using java.net.Socket but I am not able to listen to the sent messages from the server.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listen_socket_message);
    new AsyncAction().execute();
}


private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("xx.xx.xxx.xxx");
            clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddr, 8000);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

            Log.d("Exception_UnknownHost", e1.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Exception_socket", e1.getMessage());
        }

        return null;//returns what you want to pass to the onPostExecute()
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //resultis the data returned from doInbackground
        if (clientSocket.isConnected()) {
            setListener();
            Toast.makeText(SocketConnectionActivity.this, "Connected!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SocketConnectionActivity.this, "Not Connected!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

private void setListener() {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                String line = br.readLine();
                Log.d("SocketConnection",line);
                br.close();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the server socket in this code? You're creating a client socket and use this same client socket to listen to.